# "All purchase activity" or "All purchase activities"?

Tags: grammar

I am checking the grammar for my app and I find myself being unclear on which of those two I should use.

The original sentence runs as follows:

> Once you start using your card, all purchase activity will be
> displayed here.

I have conducted some research, and it looks as if either could be used.

Is there a difference between the two? If so, which one would be more appropriate and/or grammatically correct, for my app?

I would greatly appreciate any and all replies.

Comment: *Activity* is correct for your example. You can delete this: *Once you start using your card* — that should be obvious. Better yet, just say: ***Purchases will be displayed here.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former is uncountable, the latter countable.

The former is more formal, and also more elegant, in this case.

Other than that, the two mean exactly the same thing.